# Why using System.out.printf() instead of System.out.println() causes Time Limit Exceeded?

Tags: java

Recently I was solving a [question on codeforces](https://codeforces.com/contest/1385/problem/E). On coding its solution at the end I had to print the values from a 2 dimensional array for which I used,

```
for (int p = 0; p < m; p++) {
    if (positions[edges[p][0]-1] < positions[edges[p][1]-1]) {
        System.out.printf("%d %d\n", edges[p][0], edges[p][1]);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%d %d\n", edges[p][1], edges[p][0]);
    }
}
```

Using the above approach caused a Time Limit Exceed on a test case. While I replaced the above code to the one like the following, it worked.

```
for (int p = 0; p < m; p++) {
    if (positions[edges[p][0]-1] < positions[edges[p][1]-1]) {
        System.out.println((edges[p][0]) + " " + (edges[p][1]));
    } else {
        System.out.println((edges[p][1]) + " " + (edges[p][0]));
    }
}
```

What could have caused this?

My submission for reproducing [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/1385/submission/88114863)

Comment: Because `printf()` has to interpret the format string, and `println()` doesn't.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne It’s generally not expected that this minuscule difference is even measurable, let alone make the difference between pass or fail. The runtime of this problem should be dominated by other, algorithmic aspects.

Comment: Is the change from `printf` to `println` the only change you made to your code? Can you perhaps [edit] your question to include a proper [mcve] to show us?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I haven't made any other changes. The code is pretty much clustered and could not be reduced so I will provide my submission link which was accepted?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Not expected by whom? It is certainly expected by me.

Comment: maybe you could confer this LINK for more details: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overcome-time-limit-exceedtle/

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Expected by somebody who knows about what dominates algorithm runtimes. That being said, after checking OP’s link it seems that the problems are all fairly small, so that output formatting *might* dominate algorithm runtime.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The only algorithm presented here is an *O(1)* scan of an array, which calls `printf()` or `println()` *N* times. There isn't any evidence whatsoever for you or me to draw any other infererences about 'what dominates algorithm runtimes' in this specific case. Or else you are just covertly insulting me by presuming I don't know what dominates algorithm runtimes.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne O(n), not O(1). But OP linked the problem description (and now their solution), and the runtime of that algorithm is *clearly* dominated by other parts (I haven’t done a full analysis but the runtime is *at least* in O(nm)). That being said, the benchmark posted by dey is illuminating, because it shows that `System.printf` is slower than I’d have expected, at almost 5 µs per  `printf` call. Over a few hundred iterations that does add up and might break the hard limit imposed by the website.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Which is exactly what I said, and what you sneered at so unmannerly. The fact remains that the only explanation of the code posted here running at different speeds is the difference between `printf()` and `println()`, and I not only pointed it out correctly but also provided the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I created a simple test (of course it's not a benchmark, but it can simply give some conclusions):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long beforePrintln = System.nanoTime();
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        System.out.println(a + " string " + b);
    }
    long beforePrintf = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d string %d\n", a, b);
    }
    long after = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(beforePrintf - beforePrintln);
    System.out.println(after - beforePrintf);
}
```

and the results are (I run it multiple times and result are always almost the same):

```
4796301400
9976818400
```

It seems that printf (with string formating) is 2 times slower than println with string concatenation. I think printf is slower because it's much more powerfull in formatting output than simple println which just prints given line.